# Почему сперва выводится 1, а потом "Hello"?

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
let promise = new Promise((success, error) => {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      success("Hello!");
      alert(1);
    }, 2500
  );
})
promise.then((word) => {
  alert(word);
}, null)
```

Comment: Потому что так работают промисы.

Comment: Потому что никто не обещал, что success обязательно прервёт работу промиса

Comment: @andreymal и никто не обещал, что вызов success сразу вызовет все then. Скорее даже наоборот